# Separating a list at a given index

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

So I have a list of 6 variables.  I want to separate that into 2 lists, one containing the elements to the left of a given variable, and the other containing everything to the right of that given variable.  For example, if I have:

```
var1 = 25
var2 = 30
var3 = 35
var4 = 40
var5 = 45
var6 = 50

arr = [var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6]
```

I would like to separate at var 3, giving:

```
arr1 = [var1,var2]
arr2 = [var4,var5,var6]
```

It's kind of like using split(var3) on a string.  I am successfully able to do this with the following code:

```
arrleft = arr[:arr.index(var3)]

arrreverse = sorted(arr, reverse=True)
arrcut = y[:y.index(var3)]
arrright = sorted(arrcut, reverse=False)

print arrleft
print arrright
```

However, this just seems like a poor method of doing it.  Does anyone know an easier method?

Thanks.

Comment: do you need to sort the result lists too ? 
otherwise just split the input at `index` as you do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
i = arr.index(var3)
left = arr[:i]
right = arr[i+1:]
```

Comment: ah that works!  quite frankly, I just didn't know you could do that hehe

Comment: I believe you will find that you are missing element `i` from that result. For all i such that `0 <= i < len(arr)` you can assert that `arr[i:]+arr[:i] == arr`

Comment: That's what the OP asked for!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the same approach for arrright as you did for arrleft.

Something like this should do it:

```
index = arr.index(var3)
arrleft = arr[:index]
arrright = arr[index + 1:]
```

Comment: Ain't that exactly what I just said? :)

Comment: I didn't see you answer. Bad timing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
arr1 = arr[:2]
arr2 = arr[2:]
print arr1, arr2
```

gives the result you want. However you actually seem to want a list of values < var3 and a list of values > var 3. One way of doing that (using an arbitrary 35 as a limit rather than a variable) would be

```
arr.sort()
index = sum(1 for x in arr if x < 35)
arr1 = arr[:index]
arr2 = arr[index:]
print arr1, arr2
```

This has the merit that the limit need not appear in the list. If you know it does then you could use

```
index = arr.find(35)
```

instead, as that will be quicker on long lists.